# How to show uploaded image in frontend vendor dashboard?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields, dokan

I'm try to show vendor uploaded QR code in vendor dashboard.(Check screenshot 1)

**Screenshot 1**

[image: screenshot 1]

---

## Source Code

```
 add_action( 'dokan_dashboard_right_widgets', array( $this, 'get_qr_code_widget' ), 10 );

 public function get_qr_code_widget() {
   if ( ! current_user_can( 'dokan_view_sales_report_chart' ) ) 
{
            $new_qr= get_field( 'new_qr', 'Vendor');
            $Image3_URL=wp_get_attachment_url($new_qr);
            return;
        }

        echo '<img src=" '.$Image3_URL.'" width="200" height="200" alt="Lanka QR" ';
}
```

This is my advance custom field details.(Please Check screen shot 2, 3 & 4)

**screenshot 2**
[image: screenshot 2]

**screenshot 3**
[image: screenshot 3]

**screenshot 4**
[image: screenshot 4]

WordPress vendor form details.(Please Check screen shot 5)

[screenshot 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppUPV.png)

I tried so many codes but nothing work, if anyone can help me really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The `wp_get_attachment_url()` function parameter must be the attachment id, as you can see here:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_url/

The line

`$new_qr= get_field( 'new_qr', 'Vendor');`

returns the ID?

Comment: hello vdgaetano,myr friend thanks for your comment. i used below code it show the qr code but not by different qr.show same qr for every vendor can you help me to the improve my code please, i really appreciate your time & help.

Comment: my code                                                                                                                  
`$image = get_field('new_qr');
$Image3_URL=$image['url'];

 echo '<img src=" '.$Image3_URL.' " width="250" height="60" alt="Lanka QR"';`